# How to connect an oracle form to oracle database?

Tags: forms, oracle, database-connection

I'm having trouble connecting form builder to oracle database. Every time i try to connect to database an error occurs saying `ORA-12154: TNS: Could not resolve the identifier specified`. I know about password and database but I'm not sure about username. How will I know my username?

Comment: Contact your database administrator. Nobody here will know your username. The TNS error means that the name of the database you're trying to connect to is not recognised. Again, contact your DBA.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you saw usually comes when the Oracle Client isn't installed on your workstation. The Oracle Client will have the TNSNAMES entry that will point the Forms Builder to the right database.

As to what your username is, like Holodoc says, you'd have to ultimately talk to your DBA.